# audio.play() function returns a TypeError: not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As an excersize I am making a React App using the spotify API. I am trying to add a preview feature so that the user can play a 30 second mp3 on the click of a button. I have the url to the mp3, but when I try to play it, the console logs the following error: Uncaught TypeError: previewUrl.play is not a function
at PlayButton.playMusic (PlayButton.js:18:1)

first I thought that the function might not recognize the url as an .mp3 so I tried adding that extension to the url. If I open the url directly, it works, but not on my button click using a .play() function.

The code of my component is the following

```
export class PlayButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.playMusic = this.playMusic.bind(this)
    }

    playMusic() {
        const previewUrl = this.props.audioFile + '.mp3';
        previewUrl.play();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="playButton" onClick={this.playMusic} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlay} /></button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I will give you an example URL, https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/5f9499330054385118929b2af715ea5b0fcde96b?cid=b5e1d8396281443d8a60632314dbe0b9.mp3

I keep trying for this one to play, but so far to no avail.

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing `previewUrl` is a string and as such will not have a `play()` function which is what the error is saying.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke the `HTML` method `.play()` on what seems to be a string since you are doing

```
this.props.audioFile + '.mp3'
```

Make sure you are executing this method on a valid `HTMLMedia` element.

You can do so by adding the URL to a `HTML` audio tag like:

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src={this.props.audioFile + '.mp3'} type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

and then

```js
playMusic() {
  const player = document.querySelector(...) // you might want to use ref here instead
  player.play();
}
```

Comment: Hi Toni, the audioFile is the `preview_url` of the Track response object. More info here(https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-track). In this case it is a url, comparable to the example I gave. So the `.play()` function will not work on a URL? Is there any way to transfer the URL to a valid `HTMLMedia` element?

Comment: It won't work. Ad you can see in my answer you need to pass the url as the src attribute on the audio html tag.